# Have to enter password twice after losing battery power? El Capitan

Tags: macos, login

If I let my mac run flat, when I plug the magsafe back in and power it back up, it boots up with the black background and apple logo, the first logins screen is slightly greyed, after entering my pass, the screen goes black, then the normal login screen appears, I have to reenter my pass to login, this version of El-Capitan is not the public beta. How can I resolve this or is it just a current issue with El-Capitan?

Comment: Do you have FileVault enabled? That first screen sounds like it may be the FileVault password prompt, which appears before the user login prompt when the a FileVault-enabled computer is initially powered on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first screen sounds like the [FileVault](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837) password prompt, which appears before the user login prompt when a FileVault-enabled computer is initially powered on.